# How to call a SQL Server stored procedure using pdo connection in php?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures `getAllUser` and `getAllEvent()` in a SQL Server database. I can successfully connect to the database using the following code:

```
try {
    $hostname = "xxxxxx";
    $port = xxxx;
    $dbname = "xxxxx";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $pw = "xxxxxx";
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlite:server=$hostname;Database=$dbname","$username","$pw");
    echo "connected";
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
```

Now how I will call those stored procedure ....

- `getAllUser` doesn't require any parameter
- `getAllEvent` requires three parameters `@FromDate`, `@ToDate` and `@UserID`

How to do this? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepare and execute a PDO statement using [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Bind params using [PDOStatement::bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Call procedure using `CALL` syntax.

If your stored procedure returns resul set, fetch data using [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) or [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

Next is working example using PHP 7.1.12, PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.3.0+9904, SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. Both `{CALL sp_name}` and `EXEC sp_name` work.

T-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllUser]
AS BEGIN
    SELECT 'Result from stored procedure.' AS [ResultText]
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllEvent]
     @FromDate date, 
     @ToDate date,
     @UserID int
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @FromDate AS FromDate,
        @ToDate AS ToDate,
        @UserID AS UserID
END
```

PHP:

```
<?php
# Connection info
$hostname = 'server\instance,port';
$dbname   = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$pw       = 'password';

# Connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $pw);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server. ".$e->getMessage());
}

# First procedure
try {
    echo "Procedure: getAllUser"."<br>";
    $sql = "{CALL getAllUser}";
    #$sql = "EXEC getAllUser";
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
    # If your stored procedure returns information about records affected, fetch next result set
    $stmt->nextRowset();  
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
       foreach($row as $name => $value) {
          echo $name.": ".$value."<br>";
       }    
    }
    echo "<br>";
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error executing stored procedure: ".$e->getMessage());
}
$stmt = null;

# Second procedure
try {
    echo "Procedure: getAllEvent"."<br>";
    $sql = "{CALL getAllEvent(?, ?, ?)}";
    #$sql = "exec getAllEvent ?, ?, ?";
    $fromDate = '2008-08-03'; 
    $toDate = '2008-08-05';
    $userID = 123;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $fromDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $toDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $userID);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
        foreach($row as $name => $value) {
            echo $name.": ".$value."<br>";
        }   
    }
    echo "<br>";
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );
}
$stmt = null;

# End
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Comment: i tried the same code but it gives error    Failed : =>SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 unrecognized token: "{"   when i catch the exception of the procedure call  for

try {
    $sql = "{CALL getAllUser}";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
        print_r($row, true);
        echo "<br>";
    }
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );
}
$stmt = null;

Comment: @Samim You may try with `PDO->query()` - see updated answer. Thanks

Comment: What about `$sql = 'EXECUTE getAllUser'` and `$sql = 'EXECUTE getAllEvent ?, ?, ?'`

Comment: I see the code is using a sql-lite driver, but the post is tagged with SQL Server. If SQL Server, then "EXEC" or "EXECUTE" is how you call a stored procedure, not "CALL"

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth If OP uses `sqlsrv` both `CALL` and `EXEC` works.

Comment: @Samim Sorry for delay. My answer is based on your sql-server taq, so I assume that you use SQL Server (but I see that you create PDO with sqlite). Maybe this is the reason for your errors. Thanks.

Comment: i tried with the latest updated code...but it returns an error as

Error executing stored procedure: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.

Comment: @Samim Please, put SET NOCOUNT ON as first line in your stored procedure.

Comment: i dont have access to modify the store procedure...can it be done through code ? SET NOCOUNT ON

Comment: @Samim OK, then fetch next result set. Probably, stored procedure returns a result containing the number of rows affected as the first result set. See updated answer.